# Does the caravan matter?

Tags: the-banner-saga

I've completed a play through of the Banner Saga, and at no point did the absolute numbers of my Clansmen or Varls seem to matter. I understand that there are achievements associated with them, but why buy any food and supplies at all?

*Thoughts:* This may be a consequence of choosing the hardest fight each time I had a choice. I'm gussing that the armies allow you to bypass fights if they are high enough.

Comment: I think it somehow matters during the war sessions, but I'm really not sure about how it works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have enough supplies you prevent your caravan from starving, this will drive morale up. The higher your morale, the more bonuses you have in combat. For example, you can move farther and do more damage per turn.  You can also improve morale by resting your caravan.

In regards to bypassing fights, if you have high enough numbers of Clansmen and Varl, you can risk an auto resolve with your army instead of fighting every battle.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize that resting required food to improve morale. If that's the case though - can't I just starve out my caravan at a town _then_ buy supplies? It should make the food cost of resting very cheap since it's proportional to the number of people you have!

Comment: I might be wrong, but when you go up against armies of foes (hundreds), I assume if you have like 12 people in your party you either insta-die or get put into a battle that is literally impossible to win. It would be a pretty weird game that allowed 12 men to defeat an army of 500.